# How to solve Error in system2(\"cdo\", cmd.args, stdout = TRUE) : '\"cdo\"' not found\n"?

Tags: r, cdo-climate

I install climate data operators (CDO) following this link: `devtools::install_github("markpayneatwork/ClimateOperators",force = TRUE)`.

The usage is giving error. For instance , `cdo("--version",debug=FALSE)` gives the following throwback error:

```
[1] "Error in system2(\"cdo\", cmd.args, stdout = TRUE) : '\"cdo\"' not found\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in system2("cdo", cmd.args, stdout = TRUE): '"cdo"' not found>
attr(,"cdo.command")
[1] "cdo --version"
```

Can someone have an idea about how to fix it?

I am trying to process netcdf (climate date witht extension *.nc) file with R using cdo operators.

Comment: You have installed an R package, not CDO itself. Have you actually installed CDO? The error suggests you have not.